# How can I hyperlink a tooltip within an svg image map?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, imagemap, bootstrap-popover

I want to create a responsive image map (and in this case the image is also a geographic map) that displays a tooltip upon hover of a designated area. Example: An image of a city map with different restaurants users can click on hover.

Additionally, I would like to be able to insert a hyperlink within the tooltip so that users can click a link to learn more. I have tried Bootstrap/Popover. The snippet attached is a custom tooltip setup from another post. I have considered d3 although that seems somewhat complicated using vanilla js or jQuery. Ideas? Thanks.

```js
<script>
   
    function showTooltip(evt, text) {
  let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = text;
  tooltip.style.display = "block";
  tooltip.style.left = evt.pageX + 10 + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = evt.pageY + 10 + 'px';
    }

function hideTooltip() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  tooltip.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Themed Displays</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        
        <div id="tooltip" display="none" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
                        <figure id="map">
                            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                viewBox="0 0 1200 808" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
                                <image width=100%
                                    href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526778548025-fa2f459cd5c1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8bWFwfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
                                </image>
                                <g>
                                        <rect width="100" height="200" style="fill: blue;" onmousemove="showTooltip(evt, 'This is blue');" onmouseout="hideTooltip();" >
                                        </rect>
                                        <a href="www.google.com" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Some Text!">         

                                    
                                </g>
```

Comment: Well you will need to add a herf to to the area or make a function that will open a new window with the link. so something like `onclick="window.open('link')"`. Make sure to add the piece of code that I provided on the rect and not on the tooltip

Comment: Hi @AlphaWolfGamer thanks for the reply! I would like the tooltip itself to be clickable, not the entire area. For example: I have tried adding a parameter to my showTooltip function something like `function showTooltip(evt, text, link)` then using that variable within the function like `link.href=''`. Then in the html when the function is called using an argument like `onmousemove="showTooltip(evt, 'This is blue', 'www.google.com')`. Although this gave me the functionality of a clickable tooltip, the path is my/local/directory/www.google.com, which is invalid. Anyway to remove the directory?

Comment: I understand your problem but the thing is it will never work out. You see if the person moves his mouse, the tooltip will moves too. This results in the user never being able to click on the tooltip. Hence it doesn't work. So that is why I said to put the onclick function on the blue area itself. The other method is you can update the tooltip every 5 seconds. This gives the user enough time to click on the tooltip.